# cronjob files do not work properly with crontab and python

Tags: python, cron

i have a cronjob that runs every hour.
this is my command:

```
30 */1 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/sample/python/run.py 1H
```

when i execute the run.py file it runs main.py file for 90 times with different arguments via the os.system command like this:

```
os.system("/usr/bin/python3 /home/sample/python/main.py arg1 arg2")
```

when i execute the run.py file manually it works fine without any problem, but with cronjob it doesn't finish all the files and for example 10 main.py will be open for ever until i close in manually.
what is the problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try apscheduler library to do this:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
    
try:
    def func_schedule():
        print('my function')
    
        return func_schedule
    
except:
    print('Script failed')
    
execute = func_schedule
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
# my cron job / scheduler
scheduler.add_job(execute, 'cron', hour='16', minute='15', misfire_grace_time=3600)
scheduler.start()
```